# get html table td content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am working on a django project in which the main page shows a table.
I am trying to make a js query to highlight a row if it has "Unread" field.
Code:

```
fnRowCallback:  function(nRow,aData){
                            if (aData[7]=="Unread"){
                            nRow.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                            }
                },
```

I know that the relevant table data is at position 7 and so I use aData[7].
when I use normal data in the table it works.
My project requires that the field will be a xeditable field so the td is:

```
<td>
  <a href="#" data-name="Changed" data-pk="54cf97794ea5577f9449748a" data-placeholder="" data-source="/?xeditable_field=Changed" data-type="select" data-url="/" data-value="Unread" data-xeditable="xeditable">Unread</a>
</td>
```

What html js command can I use to extract the  "a href" text? What to write after aData[7].?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want your attribute data-value or innerText.
You can get the "Unread" like this:

```
aData[7].attributes['data-type'].value
```

OR

```
aData[7].innerText
```

In such cases debugging the code in console is the way to go.You will be able to see where your data is.

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround:

```
 var html=String(aData[7]);
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.innerHTML = html;
 var a= (div.innerText);
```